# Alignment issue in template, revising class file

Tags: alignment

I asked this question earlier but now I have a better grasp of the problem. I'm using a resume template (I think this one: https://github.com/treyhunner/resume) and I get this result:

[image: photo]

I want the text of the third line to line up with the second line rather than being to the left.

This is what I have (redacted for privacy):

```
\begin{rSubsection}{Job}{Dates}{University}{Location}
\item Responsible for X
\setlength{\itemindent}{0.25in}
\item Introduction to X, X, X, X, X, Metaphysics x1, X
\end{rSubsection}
```

The template is using \itemindent for the sub-bullet. This only indents the first line of the item, leaving the second line of the item out of alignment.

This is what the class file has for rSection (for some reason the lines are run together, and I don't know why it isn't greyed out as above):

\newenvironment{rSection}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byRdA.png){
\sectionskip
\MakeUppercase{\bf #1}
\sectionlineskip
\hrule
\begin{list}{}{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
}
\item[]
}{
\end{list}
}

This is what the class file has for rSubsection (same issues as above):

\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{
{\bf #1}                 \hfill                  {    #2}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{
\
{\em #3}                 \hfill                  {\em #4}
}\smallskip
\begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em}
\itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em}
}{
\end{list}
\vspace{0.5em}
}

[Following might not be included in rSubsection]\def\namesize{\huge}
\def\nameskip{\medskip}
\def\addressskip{\smallskip}
\def\sectionskip{\bigskip}
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip}

Perhaps I need to revise the class file. However, I'm not sure how to do so. Something like \itemize would allow me to nest the bullets, but I'm not sure how to do that given the way the template is set up.

Here are some photos of the class file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Turns out I had modified the template and forgotten about it, so the issue wasn't in the original template

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved by OP